# Command Line Tool for monitoring Java Heap

Tags: command-line, java

Is there any command line tool for  monitoring the heap size usage of Java in CentOS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `jps` and `jstack` to learn more about Java processes. `jstat` can also be useful for Java statistics monitoring.

Answer (score 6):

```
cd /opt/www/java/jdk/bin/

# jmap -heap <JAVA_PID>
```

Comment: had an error using it: "Cannot connect to core dump or remote debug server. Use jhsdb jmap instead." `jhsdb jmap --heap --pid xxxx`did the trick

Answer (score 5):

[jvmtop](https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop) is a command-line tool which provides a live-view at several metrics, including heap.

#### Example output of the VM overview mode:

```
 JvmTop 0.3 alpha (expect bugs)  amd64  8 cpus, Linux 2.6.32-27, load avg 0.12
 http://code.google.com/p/jvmtop

  PID MAIN-CLASS      HPCUR HPMAX NHCUR NHMAX    CPU     GC    VM USERNAME   #T DL
 3370 rapperSimpleApp  165m  455m  109m  176m  0.12%  0.00% S6U37 web        21
11272 ver.resin.Resin [ERROR: Could not attach to VM]
27338 WatchdogManager   11m   28m   23m  130m  0.00%  0.00% S6U37 web        31
19187 m.jvmtop.JvmTop   20m 3544m   13m  130m  0.93%  0.47% S6U37 web        20
16733 artup.Bootstrap  159m  455m  166m  304m  0.12%  0.00% S6U37 web        46
```

Comment: why there is an error for process 11272?

Comment: @akirekadu There are many reasons. The most common ones are  incompatible JDKs between jvmtop and the target jvm or insufficient/denied permissions. See [FAQ](https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md) for details.

Comment: Only Java 9: `/usr/local/openjdk-11 seems to be no JDK!` But: https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop/issues/109#issuecomment-622044148 :D

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to analyse the memory usage.

[GCView](http://www.tagtraum.com/gcviewer.html) might help you visualize what the GC-log shows.

If you already enabled the gc-log you could just use `tail -f` on that log.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it worked in ubuntu and redhat:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
```

For windows:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | findstr /i "HeapSize PermSize ThreadStackSize"
```

For mac

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'heapsize|permsize|threadstacksize'
```

The output of all this commands resembles the output below:

> ```
> uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 20655360        {product}
> uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 331350016       {product}
> uintx PermSize                                  = 21757952        {pd product}
> uintx MaxPermSize                               = 85983232        {pd product}
>  intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024            {pd product}
> ```
>
> java version "1.7.0_05"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b05)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)

To find the size in MB divide the value with (1024*1024)

For monitoring the live heap memory usage use jconsole.

[image: Jconsole Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

you can check this tool as well https://github.com/TeoGia/jotun

its a wrapper of jstat and outputs heap and RAM usage in json format